# How can I replace the steel mounting ring on a toilet flange?

Tags: plumbing

We found water marks on the drywall ceiling in the room under the toilet. After pulling the toilet out, there was visible water damage around the subfloor and on the drywall right underneath the flange. I am replacing the subfloor with a patch.

What should I do with the toilet flange? Does this look like it needs to be replaced? Or is there a less intrusive way to fix it from leaking in the future?

There was a blue iron ring around it that was slightly bent in the process of removing the subfloor. Now the flange is without the outer ring as seen in the second photo.

[image: initial flange with outer ring]

[image: Outer ring removed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**toilet flange repair kit**

[Example from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00068YC6E)

Get stainless steel

They are available at any typical plumbing store, maybe not at depot/lowes type places but not sure.  Explain this at a plumbing store and they will hand you what you need in 30 seconds.  Nothing complicated, because you don't have to worry about the floor makes it easier.  Numerous youtube vids will also show you what to expect.  And there's many different ways it can be done today.